# Unable to find the solution for this error : Django: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: book_comment.related_post_id

Tags: django, python-3.x, web-applications

**In short:**
   I have created a Post model and Comment model and created a comment form, I am serving a single url which will show all posts, related comment and a comment form to enter new comments. With a submission page is reloaded with new comments. But when I submit the comment I get the error:
**`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: book_comment.related_post_id`**

This is one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946577/django-db-utils-integrityerror-not-null-constraint-failed) that looked promising but I am unable to do something.
I think it is not getting parent post id.

**Long Version**:
This is my model File:

```
def user_image_path(instance, filename):
    return f"profile/user_{random.randint(1,1000)}_{filename}"

class Post(models.Model):

    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    post_creator = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    creator_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_image_path)
    post_body = models.TextField()
    post_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.post_title} **{self.post_creator}**"

class Comment(models.Model):
    related_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments")
    comment_creator = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    comment_body = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    comment_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.comment_creator}"
```

This is my form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment_creator', 'comment_body']
```

This is views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect,reverse
from .models import Comment, Post
from .forms import CommentForm
# Create your views here.

def servePage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('serve'))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    posts = Post.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'book/showpost.html', {'posts': posts, 'form': form})
```

This is my html template:

```
{% extends 'book/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Welcome to book of life</h1>
    <h2>New posts</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <li>{{ post.post_title }} by <small>{{ post.post_creator }}</small></li>
            <p>{{ post.post_created|timesince }}</p>
            <p>Content: <span>{{ post.post_body }}</span></p>
{#            <br>#}
            <h3>Comments:</h3>
            {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                <p>{{ comment.comment_creator }} => {{ comment.comment_body }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" name="comment">
            </form>
            <br><br>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Sorry for any mistakes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @cbuch1800 I finally got the answer. Here it is and the changes to file:

In template file after {`{form.as_p}}` I added a line to pass the current post Primary Key(id) to view.

**Template file:**

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="hidden" name="post_pk" value={{ post.pk }}>
  <input type="submit" name="comment">
</form>
```

In view file retrieved the post object and added the post object to related comment.
**View:**

```
def servePage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=request.POST['post_pk'])
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.related_post = post
            ## related_post from Comment model
            comment.save()
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('serve'))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    posts = Post.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'book/showpost.html', {'posts': posts, 'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this error has occurred because you have tried to create a new record in the comment model that leaves the related_post field blank, when it shouldn't be. If you are happy for this field to be left blank, you can change the field to be the following in models.py :

```
related_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", null=True)
```

Alternatively, you may not want this to be blank. If you add related_post to the fields in the form, a drop down box will be created with all the posts and you can select one of these to comment on.

You may also be able to automatically detect what post you are commenting on, but I'm unsure how this is done.

Comment: Now I get it, You are right I am not relating the comment to any post, I thought I was relating to post. Now just have to find the way to relate to that post without any drop down, It should be done automatically